# Convert Rows to columns after inner join in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

After `INNER JOIN` I get 6 rows, same `location_id`, same `location_name` but different images values, 
every `location_id` has 6 corresponding images,  [as this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0ArM.jpg)

But I want to convert image rows to columns (`img1, img2, img3 ... img6`)
so the final result table will be `[location_id, location_name, img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6]`

How can I build the result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have maximum 6 images only

```
select 
   location_id, location_name, 
   [1] as img1, 
   [2] as  img2, 
   [3] as  img3,  
   [4] as img4, 
   [5] as  img5, 
   [6] as img6
from
    (
     select 
        location_id, location_name,img_name, 
         row_number() over(partition by location_id order by img_name) rn 
     from innrjointbl
     )s
PIVOT
(MAX(img_name) for rn in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6])) p
```

**Sample SQL Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e89d94/2